# Ionic framework android text size issue

Tags: android, cordova, fonts, ionic-framework

I have started an android app using ionic framework, some text size and positions are not same in some android devices.

[image]

Comment: Can you identify the version of those devices ? The easy solution to don't have differences between android devices is to use Crosswalk plugin. It will use a custom browser on the app. The drawbacks is it increases your app size a lot.

Comment: my device android version is 4.4.4